# How to upgrade ssh-keygen using yast2 or smart

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

The ssh-keygen which I have seems to be bit old. It doesn't have -m and -y option. I would like to upgrade to latest version. In both the tools, it says "ssh-keygen" package is not found. Could you please help me with the relevant package name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since YaST uses RPM files, you should be able to use `rpm` commands to find the name of the package that contains the `ssh-keygen` file.

```
# type ssh-keygen
ssh-keygen is /usr/bin/ssh-keygen

# rpm -q -f /usr/bin/ssh-keygen
openssh-4.3p2-72.el5_7.5
```

So you need to update the `openssh` package.